# Mapping dbpedia Wikipedia entity to the Wikipedia categories he's in

Tags: nlp, wikipedia, dbpedia, named-entity-recognition, spotlight-dbpedia

I'm using dbpedia spotlight to do NER. I would like to map each entity to wikipedia categories he's under. Is there an easy way to do this?

A simple example might be if I recognized the basketball player `Michael Jordan` I would want to fetch the categories he's under, probably `NBA Players`, `Sports`, `Chicago Bulls Past Players`, Etc...

Comment: Have you actually looked at [the categories Michael Jordan is in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan#catlinks) on Wikipedia?

Comment: @svick I was hoping there might be a dbpedia entity per category. Is there a Wikipedia API to get the categories like in the link you showed?

Answer (score 3):

In DBpedia, Wikipedia categories are represented using the `dcterms:subject` property. So, to retrieve the categories for Michael Jordan, you can use SPARQL like:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT ?cat WHERE {
    :Michael_Jordan dcterms:subject ?cat
}
```

Wikipedia also has an API to get categories of an article, using [the `categories` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#categories_.2F_cl).

Comment: Note that the MediaWiki API by default lists all categories, including hidden categories. Add `&clshow=!hidden` to remove them.